# Why is the Autodesk Forge Model Derivative webhook firing multiple times?

Tags: asp.net-core, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-webhooks

I'm using the Autodesk Forge - Model Derivative service to convert a Revit (.rvt) file to IFC and SVF formats. To be notified when these conversions are done I have set up a webhook using the webhooks system Autodesk created for this purpose.

Now, when the conversion is done, the webhook succesfully sends a request to my given callback URL, but it does it more than once. And even the amount of times it fires isn't constant. It just fired the webhook twice in a minute, and then again after ten minutes. What could be a reason for this?

The problem is, that the first time the webhook fires, I can't even access the completed derivatives completely yet (I can't load the hierarchy and properties yet). It seems to be an issue on Autodesk's side, but I was wondering if anyone else encountered this problem.

This is the webhook I've created, and the only one on my account:

```
  "links": {
    "next": null
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "hookId": "<<hook id>>",
      "tenant": "jobstarted",
      "callbackUrl": "<<my url>>/callback",
      "createdBy": "2UbAPVbvWGfLAPHWLZD7Mld0bVRpI8aJ",
      "event": "extraction.finished",
      "createdDate": "2019-07-29T09:06:46.971+0000",
      "system": "derivative",
      "creatorType": "Application",
      "status": "active",
      "scope": {
        "workflow": "jobstarted"
      },
      "urn": "<<hook urn>>",
      "__self__": "/systems/derivative/events/extraction.finished/hooks/<<hook id>>"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I expect, is for the webhook to fire only once, so I can trust that I can access, download and use the entire derivative's data. Currently it's just unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such behavior typically happens when our service did not receive a successful response from your end to the callbacks. Try divert the callbacks to a third party service (e.g. ngrok) and record them to isolate the issue. And see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/basics/#callback) for more details:

> Webhooks guarantees at least once delivery. When the event occurs, the webhooks service sends a payload to the callback URL as an HTTP POST request. The webhook service expects a 2xx response to the HTTP POST request. The response must be received within 6 seconds. A non-2xx response is considered an error. In the event of an error, the webhook service will retry immediately, in 15 minutes, and 45 minutes thereafter. The webhook service retries for 48 hours and disables the webhook if the callback does not succeed during this time. You may need to reconfigure your webhooks if they are disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't believe I read over this! This explains the problem. The webhook starts an endpoint in my API which takes over 6 seconds te process, because it immediately retrieves the derivative's properties and hierarchy, which alone takes some time already.

Do you have any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: You can respond a 2xx to the webhook callbacks immediately and then/simultaneously dispatch (asynchronously) to your other handles to start the rest of your workflow  - looks to me the results of your ensuing workflow shouldn't stop you from acknowledging the callbacks themselves once you receive them...

Comment: But in asp.net core disposable objects (like the context and services) are disposed once a controller action has finished. So this means that when I respond a 2xx to the webhook, I lose some services that are required to finish the rest of my workflow.

Comment: In order to do this I'm going to look into Hangfire. Thanks for your help!